# Laravel sync a Many-to-Many relationship with pivots

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**Background Information:**

I'm creating an Asset Tracking System in Laravel.

- I have a product that has many attributes.
- The values for those attributes don't belong to the product; it belongs to its stock.

[Grafical Ilustration of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7kMU.png)

**The Problem:**

How can I update the values for the attributes? I think I have my relationships correct because I went to the database and created each record individually and it works (as you can see in the previous picture). But I have no idea how to build the code to create them through the browser.

**My Code:**

[Here is a photo of the relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W54ZO.png)

This is my Product Model:

```php
// Product.php
class Product extends Model {
    public function stocks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Stock::class)->orderBy('barcode', 'asc');
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attribute::class);
    }
}
```

This is my Attribute Model:

```php
// Attribute.php
class Attribute extends Model {
    public function getValueByBarcode($stock)
    {
        return $this->values()->whereBarcode($stock)->first()->value ?? '';
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function stocks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stock::class);
    }

    public function values()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Stock::class)->select('value');
    }
```

This is my Stock Model:

```php
// Stock.php
class Stock extends Model {
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class)->withPivot('value');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to sync from the product then relation should belong to many with a pivot table. like this...

```php
    // Product.php
    
    class Product extends Model {
   
        public function attributeStock()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Attribute::class, 'attribute_stock', 'product_id', 'stock_id')->withPivot('value');
        }
    }
```

then to access other attributes try one of the methods.

```php
$product->attributeStock()->attach($attributeId, ['value' => $value]); 
$product->attributeStock()->sync([$attributeId => ['value' => $value]]); 
Product::find(1)->attributeStock()->save($attributeId, ['value' => $value]);
```

If you still facing any difficulty to handle that method let me know.

Comment: Why are you calling the relation withPivot('stock')? I dont have a stock column in my attribute_stock table.

Comment: I have taken stock instead of value.